# Strange output when invoking model method from a runner in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, runner

I'm invoking a model method from a runner:

```
rails runner -e development "Sala.new.recipient_list2"
```

Model method:

```
def recipient_list2
  email_list = Sala.all(email)
  email_list.each do |recipient|
    puts "#{recipient}"
  end
end
```

And I'm getting the following output:

```
#<Sala:0xb05665c>
#<Sala:0xb055770>
#<Sala:0xb05566c>
#<Sala:0xb055568>
#<Sala:0xb055464>
#<Sala:0xb055360>
#<Sala:0xb05525c>
#<Sala:0xb055158>
#<Sala:0xb055054>
#<Sala:0xb054f50>
#<Sala:0xb054e4c>
#<Sala:0xb054d48>
#<Sala:0xb054c44>
#<Sala:0xb054b40>
#<Sala:0xb054a3c>
```

If I call a modified version of the method that looks like this from a controller:

```
def recipient_list
  email_list = Sala.all(email)
end
```

Controller call:

```
@list = to_be_notified.recipient_list
```

and display @list in a view, I do get a list of emails.

Why isn't it working from the runner ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add **.email** in recipient_list2 meth

```
  email_list.each do |recipient|
    puts "#{recipient.email}"
  end
```